# How to get back information in first activity from the second activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I understand how to pass data from the current activity to the second activity using intent.putExtra.

These posts explain it very well:
[activity to activity callback listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869151/activity-to-activity-callback-listener)

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

However what I'm interested in is that the second activity will send data back to the first activity that opened it.

Say, MeetActivity is my main activity, and then I activate EditProfileActivity which is the secondary activity:

```
override fun startEditProfile() {
    startActivity(EditProfileActivity.newIntent(this))
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_down)
}
```

In the EditProfileActivity I created a companion object:

```
companion object {
    fun newIntent (context: Context?) = Intent(context, EditProfileActivity::class.java)
}
```

Still I don't understand how MeetActivity which is the main activity, can receive back information from EditProfileActivity (second activity)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

From Docs

> Starting another activity doesn't have to be one-way. You can also
>   start another activity and receive a result back. To receive a result,
>   call startActivityForResult() (instead of startActivity()).

You can start an activity for result as follows

```
const val PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1 // The request code.
// ...
private fun pickContact() {
    val pickContactIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).apply {
        // Show user only the contacts that include phone numbers.
        setDataAndType(
            Uri.parse("content://contacts"),
            Phone.CONTENT_TYPE
        )
    }

    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST)
}
```

And to receive the result override the following method

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```